# Opengl screen limits at different depths

Tags: android, opengl-es, coordinates, collision, depth

I'm trying to build a 3D particle simulation with collision detection using opengl es 2.0  and I can't figure out how to detect collisions with the screen edges.

If I adjust the frustum properly and camera position I can get the X and Y screen limits to be more or less between -1.0 and 1.0 when the particle is at 0.0 z-depth, but the problem is finding the screen edges when particle z position is not zero.

Essentially, I need to check whether particles are within screen bounds at every depth. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer depends on the angle and position of the camera (projection). Can you post the parameters you send to "GLU.gluPerspective"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is frustum planes. Below there is C++/Direct3D example that you may find useful:

```
class Frustum
{
public:
    Plane plane[6]; // array of planes
public:
    // default constructor
    Frustum() 
    {
        for( unsigned int i=0; i<6; i++ ) plane[i] = Plane( 0,0,0,0 );
    }
    // perspective projection frustum
    Frustum( Matrix* matrix, 
             unsigned int width, unsigned int height, 
             float fov, float nearClip, float farClip, 
             float xFactor, float yFactor )
    {
    // frustrum planes
    Vector r_origin( matrix->_41, matrix->_42, matrix->_43 );
    Vector vpn( matrix->_31, matrix->_32, matrix->_33 );
    Vector vright( matrix->_11, matrix->_12, matrix->_13 );
    Vector vup( matrix->_21, matrix->_22, matrix->_23 );

    // for right-handed coordinate system
    vpn *= - 1, vright *= -1, vup *= -1;

    // somewhat an offset
    float orgOffset = D3DXVec3Dot( &r_origin, &vpn );

    // far plane
    plane[4].a = -vpn.x;
    plane[4].b = -vpn.y;
    plane[4].c = -vpn.z;
    plane[4].d = -farClip - orgOffset;

    // near plane
    plane[5].a = vpn.x;
    plane[5].b = vpn.y;
    plane[5].c = vpn.z;
    plane[5].d = nearClip + orgOffset;

    // field of view
    float fovx = fov * xFactor; 
    float fovy = fovx * height/width * yFactor; 
    fovx *= 0.5f, fovy *= 0.5f;
    float tanx = tan( D3DXToRadian(fovx) );
    float tany = tan( D3DXToRadian(fovy) );

    // left plane
    Vector n = (vpn * tanx) + vright;
    D3DXVec3Normalize( &n, &n );
    plane[0].a = n.x;
    plane[0].b = n.y;
    plane[0].c = n.z;

    // right plane
    n = (vpn * tanx) - vright;
    D3DXVec3Normalize( &n, &n );
    plane[1].a = n.x;
    plane[1].b = n.y;
    plane[1].c = n.z;

    // bottom plane
    n = (vpn * tany) + vup;
    D3DXVec3Normalize( &n, &n );
    plane[2].a = n.x;
    plane[2].b = n.y;
    plane[2].c = n.z;

    // top plane
    n = (vpn * tany) - vup;
    D3DXVec3Normalize( &n, &n );
    plane[3].a = n.x;
    plane[3].b = n.y;
    plane[3].c = n.z;

    for( unsigned int i=0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        n.x = plane[i].a;
        n.y = plane[i].b;
        n.z = plane[i].c;
        plane[i].d = D3DXVec3Dot( &n, &r_origin );
    }
    }
};
```

Note that to calculate intersection with frustum planes you must use worldspace coordinates of particles.